Nothing Happens When Running This Macro (No Errors/Output/Indication of Processing)
I'm pretty new to VBA and created a fairly basic macro that ran earlier. It was tied to a button that was on the wrong sheet, so I copied the macro text into Notepad, deleted the button, and have created a new button on the correct tab. I pasted the previously-working macro text into the new button's macro, but nothing happens when I hit the button or run the macro through the macros menu. Could someone please explain what looks wrong with the code? Thank you for your time!
Sub TestMacro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsPopulation As Worksheet
Set wsPopulation = Worksheets("Population")


Dim n As Integer
n = wsPopulation.Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A:A"))


Dim i As Integer


For i = 2 To n + 1

    'Define inputs and calculations worksheet.
    Dim wsCalculations As Worksheet
    Set wsCalculations = Worksheets("Calculations")
    Dim EID As Range
    Set EID = wsPopulation.Cells(i, 4)
    Dim InputEID As Range
    Set InputEID = wsCalculations.Cells(2, 2)
    
    EID.Copy
    InputEID.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    
    'Define output fields we'll want to pull.
    Dim EmpName As Range
    Set EmpName = wsCalculations.Cells(3, 2)
    Dim FICA_Due As Range
    Set FICA_Due = wsCalculations.Cells(13, 2)
    
    'Define output space.
    Dim OutputEID As Range
    Set OutputEID = wsCalculations.Cells(i + 4, 6)
    Dim OutputName As Range
    Set OutputName = wsCalculations.Cells(i + 4, 7)
    Dim OutputFICA_Due As Range
    Set OutputFICA_Due = wsCalculations.Cells(i + 4, 8)
    
    'Copy/paste key output values.
    InputEID.Copy
    OutputEID.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    EmpName.Copy
    OutputName.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    FICA_Due.Copy
    OutputFICA_Due.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    

    
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

With no errors, it's tough to debug. I consulted a coworker and he didn't see anything wrong jump out at him. I've been reading on StackExchange, but I can't tell what could've happened when the macro had worked before. I have confirmed that macros are still enabled in this workbook in the settings. I've reinitiated Excel multiple times.

put breaks in the code and step through and see if it is actually doing each line.

is range A:A on that sheet full of numbers or is it text?

n = wsPopulation.Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A:A")) should probably be n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(wsPopulation.Range("A:A")) otherwise you're counting in ColA of whatever happens to be the active worksheet.

@TimWilliams Yes, thank you! That explains why it was working on one tab and not when I switched where the button was!

Are you sure the code is executed when you push the button, did you also try it in the VB editor using F5?
I tried the code using guessed worksheets and things do happen, could you add the workbook (or if it is confidential just the 2 sheets with fake data).
tnx
